# Easy way to change Locale based currency formatting in Java

Tags: java, localization, currency, number-formatting

Below is some code that shows how we can format currency based on Locale.

Is there an easy way to configure this behaviour in Java? For example, let's say that I want to make a slight adjustment to how currency is formatted in Italian, by putting the Currency symbol after the amount, instead of in front of the amount.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    displayCurrency(Locale.ENGLISH);
    displayCurrency(Locale.FRENCH);
    displayCurrency(Locale.ITALIAN);
}

static public void displayCurrency( Locale currentLocale) {

    Double currencyAmount = new Double(9876543.21);

    DecimalFormat currencyFormatter = (DecimalFormat) 
        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentLocale);

    System.out.println(currentLocale.getDisplayName() + ": " +
        currencyFormatter.format(currencyAmount));
}
```

Output:

```
English: ¤9,876,543.21
French: 9 876 543,21 ¤
Italian: ¤ 9.876.543,21
```

Comment: Just specify your own format string by calling the [`DecimalFormat(String pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat%28java.lang.String%29) constructor.

Comment: @Andreas that's what I would like to prevent. I'm using a standard jsp taglib for formatting currency. If I could find an easy way to change this behaviour, I could keep using this taglib, instead of implementing my own.